# The reac-admin showNotification display the same snackbar color

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

I'm using the showNotification to display messages to the user.
The messages are shown and hidden as excpected bu the color was same (gray) with any level :

```
this.props.showNotification(error.message, 'error')

this.props.showNotification('Done', 'success')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should document this correctly. The supported notification types are `info` and `warning`